# Periodically delete long dicts / lists in Python good practice?

Tags: python

I have been writing a long script that occasionally builds large dicts and/or lists, and I was wondering if performance could be improved by deleting them with `del` when I'm finished using them. Or is it normal practice to leave these objects hanging around to be taken care of by garbage collection? What is the best practice here? Thanks.

Comment: If I remember correctly, deleting values from a list/dict will just release the values to the GC and stop referencing them in the list dict, so effectively you still have all that memory to be handled by the GC, it's just broken into small pieces. I may be wrong though, i haven't done extensive study of the python GC

Comment: In CPython, if they go out of scope, they're collected (bar circular references). It's also not clear from your question if you mean deleting list members or entire lists...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`del` is not equivalent to free(3).  It doesn't force Python to free memory.  It may not end up freeing memory at all.  You should avoid associating it with memory usage entirely.

The only thing `del` does is delete a *name* from its scope.  (Or delete an item from a collection, or delete an attribute.  But I assume that's not what you're talking about here.)

Effectively, this:

```
del foo
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
del LOCAL_SCOPE['foo']
```

So this doesn't free any memory:

```
massive_list = list(range(1000000))
same_massive_list = massive_list
del massive_list
```

...because all it does is remove the *name* `massive_list`.  The underlying object still has another name, `same_massive_list`, so it doesn't go away.  `del` isn't a secret hook for controlling Python's memory management; it's just one of several ways to *ask* Python to *invoke* its memory management.

(By the way, CPython is refcounted + cycle-collected, not garbage-collected.  Objects are *immediately* freed as soon as the last reference to them disappears.  Garbage does not lie around waiting to be cleaned up.  Of course, other implementations do different things; PyPy, for example, is garbage collected.)

Now, if the name you use is the *only* name for the list/dict/whatever, then `del` will certainly cause its refcount to drop to zero, so it'll be freed.  **But**, since `del`'s semantics are really about removing *names*, I wouldn't use it in this case.  I'd just let the variable drop out of scope (if practical), or reassign the name to a blank list, or `None`, or whatever makes sense for your program.  You can even empty the list in-place, which will work even if there are several names for the same list:

```
foo = list(range(1000000))
bar = foo
foo[:] = []
# Both `bar` and `foo` still refer to the original list, but now it's empty
```

You can do the same thing to a dict with `d.clear()`.

The only place I'd use `del` on a name is in a class or module scope, where I temporarily need some helper value but *really really* don't want to expose it as part of the API.  This is really rare, but it's the only case I've run into where I actually want the semantics of "remove this name".

Comment: Like this answer, particularly the bit about emptying containers.

Comment: I find `del foo[:]` to be more concise.

Comment: i like to reserve `del` only for removing names.  lists and dicts both have `.pop`, and lists have slice syntax, so there's little need for a special construct; deleting variables can only (ish) be done with `del`.  this avoids a scanning problem, too: when you see `del super_duper_long_name[2]`, you can't actually tell which flavor of `del` it is until you read to the end of the line.

Answer (score 3):

`del` is usually not necessary.

In CPython, objects go away when there are no references to them. `del` deletes only one reference to the object; if there are still other references to the object, it will stay around, and `del` has really done nothing to improve your memory situation.

Conversely, simply reassigning the variable to a different object (say, creating a new empty list at the top of a loop) will *also* end up with one less reference to the object, implicitly doing the same as `del`. If there are no other references to the object at this point, it will be freed immediately.

Also remember that local variables go away when the function returns, so you don't need to explicitly `del` any names you've defined in a function.

An exception is circular references, where two (or more) objects reference each other but none is actually reachable through a name; Python periodically garbage-collects these, but you can free them up faster if you break the circle when you're done with the objects. (This may require as little as one `del`!) Circumstances in which this is useful are probably pretty rare, though.

In IronPyothon (which runs on the .NET CLR) or Jython (which runs on the JVM), optimal memory management strategies may differ, since the garbage collector of the underlying VM is used.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of Python (compared with languages like C) is that in general you don't have to worry about the details of memory management and you can concentrate on the purpose of your program.

So my advice would be to don't bother *unless* you have reason to do so (e.g. python is eating all your RAM).